# How to generate a uniform simple path from a rectangular grid graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, random-walk, algorithmic-randomness

I have an $m \times n$ grid graph. I want to generate a simple path from $(1,1)$  to $(m, n)$ uniformly from the set of all such paths. (Note I am *not* constrainted to move only right/down; the path may move up/right/left/down at any step)

I can easily generate a random path by choosing each step randomly (and backtracking if I get stuck). However, the distribution won't be *uniform*, as if you step uniformly in each direction, any direction that leads to fewer paths will be biased towards in the resulting distribution of paths.

I think if you could count the number of paths with a given prefix, you could simply choose which direction to move next by weighting by the amount of paths in that direction. However, [Wikipedia suggests without a citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) that counting such paths is thought to be a hard problem, so this would not lead to a tractable algorithm.

---

If this can't be done (efficiently), is there a good approximation scheme that gets close?

---

A similar problem is selecting a random MST uniformly, which Wilson's Algorithm accomplishes. I don't have a good enough understanding of why Wilson's Algorithm works to see if ideas from it can be applied to this situation.

Comment: It is hard because people who have tried to calculate this have found it hard.  For example for an $n \times n$ grid, there are results up to $n=27$ at [OEIS A007764](https://oeis.org/A007764https://oeis.org/A007764) but no formula though there is a paper with bounds on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506341), while for a $6 \times n$ grid there is a $76$ term recurrence at [OEIS A145403](https://oeis.org/A145403).